# for in loop not working as expected javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an object, `Object { 2014-01-30=[1], 2014-02-01=[1]}`

and an array called fechasPeriodo,

so why is the following code:

```
fechasPeriodo = [];
            for(var property in SelectedDates) {
            fechasPeriodo.push(new Date(property));
            }
```

producing this result `[Date {Wed Jan 29 2014 18:00:00 GMT-0600}, Date {Fri Jan 31 2014 18:00:00 GMT-0600}]`

Edit: I'd expect the result to be Thu Jan 30 2014 etc. , Sun 02 Feb 2014.

Actually it's a problem only because I'm trying to define a range of dates in datepicker using a Google Calendar feed. So the following code:

```
if(fechasPeriodo.length > 1) {
            r[1] = fechasPeriodo[0] <= date && date <= fechasPeriodo[1] ?"Highlighted"+SelectedDates[key][0].replace(/\s/g, "_"):"Highlighted-unknown";
            }
```

I'd expect to highlight a range from the 30th Jan to the 02nd of February. But if you can guide me as to why it isn't working, I'd be very grateful, I'm following this fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/qaEuj/

At the risk of being downvoted again I have to say that I still don't understand why my last bit of code above isn't working like the fiddle I mention, so here's my complete code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var fechaDefecto = new Date('2014/01/01');
    var fechaFin = new Date('2014/08/31');
    SelectedDates = null;

    /*SelectedDates[new Date('12/25/2014')] = new Date('12/25/2014');
    SelectedDates[new Date('12/12/2014')] = new Date('12/12/2014');
    SelectedDates[new Date('06/06/2014')] = new Date('06/06/2014');*/
    $('#tiposFechas').change(function() {
    $.getJSON("https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/cide.edu_sm151i2pdhu2371vq8hamcver4@group.calendar.google.com/public/full?q="+encodeURI($(this).val()), {"alt" : "json"}, function(data) {
    SelectedDates = {};
    $.each(data.feed.entry, function(i, entry) {
    var key = entry.gd$when[0].startTime.substr(0, 10)
    var clave = entry.gd$when[0].endTime.substr(0, 10);
    if(key in SelectedDates === false || clave in SelectedDates === false) {
    SelectedDates[key] = [];
    SelectedDates[clave] = [];
    }
    SelectedDates[key].push(entry.title.$t);
    SelectedDates[clave].push(entry.title.$t);  
    });
    $('#cal').datepicker("refresh");
    });
    });

    $('#cal').datepicker(
    {
            beforeShowDay: function (date) {
            var r = [true, ""];
            if (SelectedDates === null) {
            r[1] = "Highlighted-unknown";
            }
                else {
                fechasPeriodo = [];
                for(var property in SelectedDates) {
                fechasPeriodo.push(new Date(property));
                //alert(property);
                }
                var key = $.datepicker.formatDate("yy-mm-dd", date);
                if(key in SelectedDates) {

                if(fechasPeriodo.length > 1) {
                r[1] = fechasPeriodo[0] <= date && date <= fechasPeriodo[1] ?"Highlighted"+SelectedDates[key][0].replace(/\s/g, "_"):"Highlighted-unknown";
                }
                else {
                r[1] = "Highlighted"+SelectedDates[key][0].replace(/\s/g, "_"); 
                }
                r[2] = SelectedDates[key].join(", ");
                }
            }
            return r;
}, 
        minDate : fechaDefecto,
        maxDate : fechaFin, 
        numberOfMonths: [3,3]   
    });
});
```

I'm hoping someone points out a cause, even if it's a criticism, because it's getting late.

I must say I tried this: 
`r[1] = new Date(fechasPeriodo[0].getYear(), fechasPeriodo[0].getMonth(), fechasPeriodo[0].getDate()) <= date && date <= new Date(fechasPeriodo[1].getYear(),fechasPeriodo[1].getMonth(),fechasPeriodo[1].getDate()) ?"Highlighted"+SelectedDates[key][0].replace(/\s/g, "_"):"Highlighted-unknown";`

But didn't work either. May there be a problem in the way I'm representing the dates when I call new Date in the line `fechasPeriodo.push(new Date(property));` and the way I'm comparing them?

Comment: what is the expected result

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/68bbo42t/1/

Comment: thanks @torazaburo but that didn't work, I stick to the original syntax

Answer (score 2):

It's just the difference between the UTC and non-UTC representation.

```
new Date('2014-01-30').toString(); //Wed Jan 29 2014 19:00:00
new Date('2014-01-30').toUTCString(); //Thu, 30 Jan 2014 00:00:00
```

Try `fechasPeriodo[0].toUTCString();` and I'm pretty sure it will return what you expect.

Comment: thanks @plalx now I can see a closer result `["Thu, 30 Jan 2014 00:00:00 GMT", "Sat, 01 Feb 2014 00:00:00 GMT"]` but I'm still confused because the code that should assign a class to each of the dates that fall in the period isn't working. Does anyone know why? I mean that it renders the css class for the first and last dates of the cells in the datepicker, but not the ones in the middle. Like I said the fiddle I'm following is a working example

Comment: @gerardoflores It's because your dates are now strings. Do not convert them to strings. Just use the UTC representation for display purposes.

Comment: Yes I realize that so I'll stick with the original date objects but oddly enough the middle date between the 29th and the 31th of January doesn't get the class defined. In fact only the first date gets the class defined as I expect. Again I provide the updated fiddle that I mentioned, where everything works properly